# Handle command prompt error within PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run a few command prompt commands like `schtasks` within a PowerShell script. I would like to know how to handle errors thrown by the command in PowerShell.

I tried:

- `& cmd.exe /c 'schtasks /Query /TN xx || echo ERROR'`
- `& cmd.exe /c 'ping.exe 122.1.1.1 && exit 0 || exit 1'`
- `Invoke-Expression -Command:$command`

I'm unable to run these commands and ignore or catch exception in a `try..catch` block of the PowerShell script. I know there are libraries but I'm limited to PowerShell v2.0.

Comment: Check `$LASTEXITCODE` after each invocation of `cmd.exe` - a nonzero value indicates that the command failed. Normally you can just let the command itself report its exit code, without the need for a `||` clause. However, if you do use one, be sure that it ends with `exit 1` (or a different nonzero exit code); in your first command, because you execute `echo` (as the one and only command) in the `||` clause, the overall exit code will mistakenly be `0`.

Comment: yes, but if the command throws an error, the powershell script also displays that error, i want to avoid seeing that error message.

Comment: To suppress the command's stderr output, append `2>NUL` directly to the command in question (inside the single quotes); e.g. `'schtasks /Query /TN xx 2>NUL'`. To suppress stdout output also, add `>NUL`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

External commands usually set a non-zero exit code if they're terminating with an error, so you could check if the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$LASTEXITCODE` has a non-zero value:

```
& cmd /c 'schtasks /Query /TN xx'
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  'an error occurred'
}
```

Note, however, that there are some programs that use non-zero exit codes for non-error information, (e.g. `robocopy`, which uses the exit codes below 8 for status information, or `choice`, which uses the exit code to indicate the chosen option).

Error messages of the external command can be suppressed by redirecting the error output stream, either in CMD:

```
& cmd /c 'schtasks /Query /TN xx 2>nul'
```

or in PowerShell:

```
& cmd /c 'schtasks /Query /TN xx' 2> $null
```