# How to handle errors in a way that works the same whether the script runs in "regular" powershell console or in powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have this simple script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try 
{ 
    cmd /c mklink a .\DataSvc.sln 
} 
catch 
{ 
    "Failed" 
}
```

(file DataSvc.sln exists)

When I run it in ISE powershell console it prints "Failed", when I do it from the "regular" powershell console it outputs "You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.":

**ISE:**

[image]

**Regular:**

[image]

How am I supposed to write it so that it prints "Failed" in both cases?

**EDIT 1**

You must run it as a regular account (not elevated) with Windows 10 Developer Mode turned off. If you do not know what Windows 10 Developer Mode is, then you are fine (for this question).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755510#34755677

Comment: I am failing to see the relevance. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: `try { & cmd /c mklink a .\DataSvc.sln  2> $null; if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {'Failed'} } catch {'Failed'}`. "_prints "Failed" in both cases_".  Would be nice if comments kept newlines....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, different hosts treat *stderr* output from *external programs* differently.

- The ISE routes stderr output to PowerShells own error stream, which explains why anything written to stderr triggers the `try` / `catch` handler.

  - On a side node: Consider switching from the obsolescent ISE to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell). Future development efforts are focused there, and the behavior doesn't differ from the console (at least in this respect).
- The regular console patches stderr output *through to the console*, in which case no error is triggered.

Due to a [*bug*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002), you can currently (Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1) trigger an error in the console just by *redirecting* stream number `2` in PowerShell:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
  cmd /c 'echo tostderr >&2' 2>&1 # even 2>$null would trigger an error(!)
} catch {
  "Failed"
}
```

However, I wouldn't rely on that, as the bug may - and hopefully will - get fixed.

Taking a step back: As implied by the link in the comments, whether an external program failed should only ever derived from its *exit code*, not from the presence of stderr output, as many program use stderr output to report information *other than errors* (such as diagnostic information or mere warnings).

Thus, `if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)` alone should be used to determine failure.

---

If, for some reason, you *do* need to infer failure from the presence of  stderr output - e.g., because some programs don't properly reflect failure in their exit codes - you can try the following approach, which should work now as well as after the aforementioned bug is fixed:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
  cmd /c 'echo tostderr >&2' 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) { Throw $_ }
    $_
  }
} catch {
  "Failed"
}
```

This relies on merging the error stream into the success stream and then detecting stderr-originated lines by their type.

Note that while PowerShell-internally you can collect a command's error output in a *variable* with common parameter `-ErrorVariable` / `-ev`, there is no analogous mechanism when calling *external* programs; however, introducing such a mechanism has been proposed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332).