# Omit Specific Warning From FFMPEG Console Output In Powershell

Tags: powershell, filter, ffmpeg, warnings

having some troubles with a warning spamming my FFmpeg console output, hoping someone can help.

I output to multiple files simultaneously while utilizing segmentation, to keep each part synchronized without audio drift I need to set everything to a constant integer frame rate. Problem with this is when using -framerate with a integer frame rate (to duplicate frames) you get the warning "Past duration 0.x too large" constantly spammed in your console.

I've tried just about every "solution" to this warning online but each has it's drawbacks. I found that simply silencing the console with -loglevel error and using -stats to retain some level of verbosity to be the best solution thus far, but then I can't see what segment I'm currently writing to in the console which is highly annoying. There isn't a log level option to silence warnings exclusively and from my extensive experimentation no other way to organically prevent the warning from spamming the console in my use case.

In comes Powershell (I was using CMD), I'm hoping I can catch the warning and omit it from the console output using some sort of filter. I've tried throwing this at the end of my command:

```
| Where-Object {$_ -notcontains 'Past'}
```

but no luck. I'm pretty inexperienced with Powershell so forgive me, from what I understand you want some sort of object following "$_" but I don't think FFmpeg separates text with headers or anything like that so I'm not really sure what to put there.

Anyways, any help would be appreciated.

Full command (without console suppression):

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M `
-i audio="Analog (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M `
-i audio="ADAT (5+6) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -video_size 3840x2160 -rtbufsize 2147.48M `
-framerate 60 -pixel_format nv12 -i video="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)":audio="ADAT (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M `
-i audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -r 25 -f lavfi -rtbufsize 2147.48M -i color=c=black:s=50x50 `
-map 4,0 -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r 25 -rc-lookahead 50 -forced-idr 1 -sc_threshold 0 -flags +cgop `
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 16K -minrate 16K -maxrate 16K -bufsize 16k `
-c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -vf "fps=25" -af "aresample=async=250" -vsync 1 -ss 00:00:01.479 `
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 `
-segment_format_options max_delay=0 C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Theirs\TPC%02d.ts `
-map 4,1 -map 1 -c:v libx264 -r 25 -rc-lookahead 50 -forced-idr 1 -sc_threshold 0 -flags +cgop `
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 16K -minrate 16K -maxrate 16K -bufsize 16k `
-c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -vf "fps=25" -af "aresample=async=250" -vsync 1 -ss 00:00:00.850 `
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 `
-segment_format_options max_delay=0 C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Soundboard\SPC%02d.ts `
-map 2:0,2:1 -map 2:1 -c:v h264_nvenc -r 60 -rc-lookahead 120 -forced-idr 1 -strict_gop 1 -sc_threshold 0 -flags +cgop `
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -preset: llhp -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 250M -minrate 250M -maxrate 250M -bufsize 250M `
-c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -af "atrim=0.086, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS, aresample=async=250" -vsync 1 `
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 `
-segment_format_options max_delay=0 C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\PC\PC%02d.ts `
-map 4,3 -map 3 -c:v h264_nvenc -r 25 -rc-lookahead 50 -forced-idr 1 -strict_gop 1 -sc_threshold 0 -flags +cgop `
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -preset: llhp -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 16K -minrate 16K -maxrate 16K -bufsize 16K `
-c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -vf "fps=25" -af "pan=mono|c0=c0, adelay=120|120, aresample=async=250" -vsync 1 `
-ss 00:00:00.065 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 `
-segment_format_options max_delay=0 C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Camera\CPC%02d.ts
```

Comment: Assuming the warnings are written to stderr, you can try the filtering technique described in the bottom section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51433909/45375

Comment: `2>$null` OR `-ea silentlycontinue` are the normal ways to tell a command to mute it's errors

Comment: Upgrade to a git build from July or later. That warning was sent to a higher loglevel than the default one you're using.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, I'll have to try Gyan's solution first. I stick with an FFmpeg build for a while because it seems each time I upgrade I run into another issue to be solved, once I find one that works hard to move from. I do believe this build is from earlier this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gyan suggested in the comments of my original question - FFmpeg builds since July 2018 send the warning to a higher loglevel than the default one.

After updating the warning message is no longer spammed in my console.